# Particle and probability density

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In one home exercise I was asked to find the expression for the probability that a classical particle is in height $z + dz$. I got the exact result which is:

$$\text{prob}(z,z+dz)=\beta mge^{-\beta mgz }dz$$ where $e^{-\beta mgz }$ is the probability density function.

Then I am asked to find the particle density for an arbitrary height value $z$.

Without understanding why (and this is the point of my thread) I simply multiply the particle density in the surface of the earth with the probability density, so that I can get the particle density in a specific height. That means:

$$\rho(z) = \rho(0) e^{-\beta mgz }$$

Can someone explain the logic for the above expression?

For me personally, it doesn't make sense. If I know the probability density for a single particle, then I can predict how high the possibility (=probability) is that the particle is located in an interval $z - z+ dz$. If I now multiply the probability density with the particle density for z=0 then what I should get is the probability that all the particles are located in the height-interval $z - z+dz$, how exactly is this interpreted as particle density, and not probability?

Answer (score 0):

You intuition is leading you astray, as:

$$\rho(0)e^{-\beta mgz}$$

doesn't even have the dimensional of probably per unit height ($[L]^{-1}$), so it can't be the probability that all the particles are in $(z,z+dz)$.

Suppose you confine you self to a column with cross sectional area $A$. Now add $N$ particles to this volume (label them $j$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,N). Each particle is independent, and distributed according to:

$$ p(z_j) = \beta mge^{-\beta mg z_j} $$

so that:

$$\langle n(z) \rangle =\sum_j^Np(z_j) = N\beta mg e^{-\beta mg z}=N(0)e^{-\beta mg z} $$

Now divide by the area $A$ to get density:

$$ \rho(z)=\rho(0)e^{-\beta mg z} $$

Note that you can integrate $\langle n(z) \rangle$ to get the pressure at any height too:

$$ p(z) = \int_z^{\infty}\frac{mg}A\langle n(z') \rangle dz'$$

$$p(z) = -\frac{mgN}A e^{-\beta mgz'}\big{|}^{\infty}_z = mgNe^{-(\beta mg)z}=p_0e^{-z/z_0}$$

where

$$p_0 = \frac{mgN}A$$

is the surface pressure and

$$ z_0 = \frac 1{\beta mg}$$

is the scale height.

Comment: Your explanation is sufficient but there is one thing I want to understand : As I said above $e^{- \beta m g z }$ is the probability density function for one single particle. In my book then it says : In order to find the particle density at height z you multiply  the expression of probability density function of a particle with the particle density. In other words we multiply nr. of particles per volume with pdf and we get particle density. How does this intuitively makes sense?